# In-app billing error: Необходимо войти в аккаунт Google

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Для покупки контента из приложения использую [гайд](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html)

При вызове метода `onIabPurchaseFinished()` у `IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` выдает следующее сообщение:

> "Необходимо войти в аккаунт Google"

На устройстве запущен аккаунт разработчика (который добавлен в разработчики в google консоли).

Создал `apk` и загрузил его в альфа-версию на `GooglePlay`. **В чем может быть проблема?**